# Cloudformation template Lambda environment variable error - Value of property Variables must be an object with String

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I want to set environment variiable for my lambda function using cloudformation mappings. Hence I am using `Fn::FindInMap` to get the value of variable from a mapping. But I am getting the error - `Value of property Variables must be an object with String (or simple type) properties`

```
Mappings:
  DomainResourceMapping:
    DUBCrossAccountIAMRole:
      beta: "xyz"
      prod: "act"

Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: '...t'
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: ...
        Key: ...
      Description: nn
      Timeout: 20
      MemorySize: 512
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DUB_CROSS_ACCOUNT_IAM_ROLE:
          - Fn::FindInMap:
            - DomainResourceMapping
            - DUBCrossAccountIAMRole
            - {Ref: Stage}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `DUB_CROSS_ACCOUNT_IAM_ROLE` to be an array. Try

```
 Environment:
    Variables:
      DUB_CROSS_ACCOUNT_IAM_ROLE:
        Fn::FindInMap:
        - DomainResourceMapping
        - DUBCrossAccountIAMRole
        - {Ref: Stage}
```

or using the short syntax

```
 Environment:
    Variables:
      DUB_CROSS_ACCOUNT_IAM_ROLE: !FindInMap [ DomainResourceMapping, DUBCrossAccountIAMRole, !Ref Stage
```